# Actualizar una columna de un df con datos de otra columna de otro df

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Dispongo de los siguientes df.

```
# df compras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nombres = ["manzanas", "kiwi", "limones", "peras"]
cantidad =[5, 7, 3, 9]
compras = pd.DataFrame({"nombres":nombres,                "cantidad":cantidad})
print(compras)

# df precios
fechas=['2016-01-04', '2016-01-05', '2016-01-06', '2016-01-07',
               '2016-01-08', '2016-01-09', '2016-01-10', '2016-01-11']
frutas=["peras", "peras", "manzanas", "limones", "limones", "kiwis", "platanos", "platanos" ]
precios=[3, 8, 4, 5, 6, 10, 5, 3]
precios = pd.DataFrame({"fechas":fechas,
                "frutas":frutas,
                "precios":precios}
precios[:3]
```

Necesito crear una columna **"importe**" en el df precios, con el importe del producto de cada valor en la columna **"precios**" de este df , por la cantidad correspondiente a cada fruta adquirida del df compras. Para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
precios["importe"] = 0
for key, valor in precios["frutas"].iteritems():
    aux1 = precios[precios["frutas"] == valor]
    aux2 = compras[compras["nombres"] == valor]
    precios["importe"] = aux1["precios"] * aux2["cantidad"]    
precios
```

Me devuelve

```
    fechas  frutas  precios     importe
0   2016-01-04  peras   3   NaN
1   2016-01-05  peras   8   NaN
2   2016-01-06  manzanas    4   NaN
```

Lo cual no es correcto. ¿Cuál es  mi error?.

Answer (score 0):

Creo haberlo resuelto con un **"merge"**.

```
precios["importe"] = aux1["precios"] * aux2["cantidad"]
```